# python IndexError list index out of range + how to break a while then also restart the while statement

Tags: python

`Please Swipe Your Card: chend151
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\attendance\Attendance 3.py", line 42, in <module>
    clcode = dataList[period][d]
IndexError: list index out of range`

I get this error when running my code, I can't seem to find what the problem is :/

My Code:

```
import csv
import datetime
import os

class_ = 'N004'

while (1):
    #Day & Time Checker
    format = "%H%M%S"
    format_ = "%H%M"
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    s = today.strftime(format) #Time in 24hour
    s2 = today.strftime(format_)
    d = datetime.datetime.today().weekday() #Day of week (0-5)
    period = -1 #If they scan it outside of the dedicated periods it defaults to a unknown period`

    #Period Checker
    if "084500" < s < "094000":
        period = 0
    if "094000" < s < "104000":
        period = 1
    if "112000" < s < "121500":
        period = 2
    if "121500" < s < "131500":
        period = 3
    if "133500" < s < "143000":
        period = 4

    #Magnetic Card Reader Output & Attendance (Default = 0)
    attendance = '0'
    eqid = str(input('Please Swipe Your Card: '))

    #Class Code Reader
    dataList = []
    with open(class_+'.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
      csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
      for row in csvreader:
         dataList.append(row)
    csvfile.close()

    #Class Code
    clcode = dataList[period][d] 

    #CSV Writer
    ofile = open('Attendance.csv', "a")
    writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow([eqid, period+1, clcode, attendance]) 
    ofile.close()

`#os.rename("J:/attendance/Attendance.csv", "J:/G_DRIVE/Attendance.csv")`

Sorry for the formatting still can't seem to understand how the formatting works for code :c 

Also, extra question, in my while statement I want to have an if statement that 

`if eqid == "N004":
    class_ = "N004"
    break
```

I know indentation is off but how would I break the loop then restart it? so I want if they enter `N004` it breaks the loop sets `class_ = 'N004'` then restarts the while loop and if they don't enter `N004` the loop would just continue like normal.

Thank you, hopefully this makes sense.

EDIT: I will try explain what I want, I think I do have more than one question, firstly Thank you for helping. What I want is too have one print statement that asks for the user to swipe their card or insert their username and in the same print statement is asks for them to type the current class they are in (eg N004') , whatever they type gets exported to a csv file, I have that all setup already, but when they type in a class so for example N004 I want the while loop to break so N004 doesnt get exported to a CSV file. I'm not the best at explaining what I want in 300 characters

Comment: Are you looking for `continue`? I'm not sure what "restarts the while loop" would mean.

Comment: you should use function for it you can call function if certain condition satisfies

Comment: @smarx I mean when I `break` the `while` loop I want the loop to then start again. so if the user inputs `N004` the loops stops there then the loops starts again from the top.

Comment: for your error for `list index out of range` for `dataList[period][d]` ... `period` is the index of some list called `dataList` and may be out of range. or `dataList[period]` contains a list, and at some point `d` is out of range of that list.

Comment: The Error was happening becasue `period` was = to -1

Answer (score 0):

```
eqid = str(input('Please Swipe Your Card: '))

if eqid == "N004":
    class_ = "N004"
    continue
else:
    print ("Didn't work")
```

Comment: do pass and continue do the same thing? sorry im not very good with python, i kinda just mash lots of things together to get stuff to work

Comment: I actually used @smarx comment after I was doing some more research and found someone else using continue. `Are you looking for continue? I'm not sure what "restarts the while loop" would mean.`

Comment: Do you want credit or something? Is that why your angry? I just posted my answer as that is what I'm using

Comment: Yeah it still starts with `while(1)`